# How to evaluate the performance of a binary tree implemented via a linked list or an array list?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, linked-list, binary-tree

This falls under "a software algorithm" from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

This is from an interview question http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Yelp-Software-Engineering-Intern-Interview-Questions-EI_IE43314.0,4_KO5,32_IP2.htm,

particularly "performance of binary tree if implemented thru array or linkedlist"

How would you go about implementing a binary tree via an array or a linked list?

The way I was taught to do it was by having a linked node type of structure that has two pointers, left and right, that is (from https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/12wi/lectures/02-22/programs/IntTreeNode.java)

```
public class IntTreeNode {
      public int data;            
      public IntTreeNode left;    
      public IntTreeNode right;   
      public IntTreeNode(int data) {
               this(data, null, null);
      } 

     public IntTreeNode(int data, IntTreeNode left, IntTreeNode right) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
      }
}
```

And then in the actual binary tree

```
public class IntTree {
        IntTreeNode overallRoot;
        public IntTree() {
              overallRoot = null;
        }
         ....
  }
```

How would you go about this if you were just using an array or a linked list(one pointer)?

But anyways this is supposed to be a quick fire question. Even if you didn't implement the tree, which you aren't supposed to, how would you analyze the performance of the tree? Doesn't the performance depend on the state of the tree, like if it is a BST? Like for a BST, find would be O(log n) because you're cutting off half the tree each time.

How would you analyze performance based on these two implementations right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but this is what I thought of.
Basically, you can store the nodes in the tree as elements of an array/list.

For arrays, think of something like this:

```java
public class Node {
    public int data;
    public int left;
    public int right;
    ...
}
```

Your tree would be an array of `Node`s (`Node[] tree`), such that the root would be the first element `tree[0]`.
Every element refers to its left and right children as indices in the array.
For example, `tree[ tree[0].left ]` would be the left child of the root.
A `left` value of `-1` could indicate that the node does not have a left child; similarly for `right`.

For example, consider the following tree:

```
     5
  /     \
2         8
 \       / \
  3     6   9
```

Suppose you have initially allocated 10 elements in your array.
Since you have fewer than 10 nodes in the tree, some of them will be `null`.
Here is what it could look like:
(I am representing each `Node` as a `(data,left,right)` tuple)

```
{ (5,1,2) , (2,-1,4) , (8,5,3) , (9,-1,-1) , (3,-1,-1) , (6,-1,-1) , null , null , null , null }
```

Thus for the node `(8,5,3)`, you can tell that its left child is the sixth element (node `(6,-1,-1)`) and its right child is the fourth element (node `(9,-1,-1)`).

The performance of the insertion/deletion functions could vary depending on your precise implementation.
A similar idea can hold for linked lists (but remember that they do not have random access: finding the `i`-th element requires traversing the list, element by element).

Hope this helps.

Comment: tuple means python right? Nice implementation though. I like this idea. So could a right away answer be that performance with an array based implementation is faster because a linked list does not have random access?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant it in the math sense: I just mean that I'm representing the node as three integers.

Comment: Yes, I would think that in this case the array implementation would be better. Insertion can be done logarithmically for instance. The caveat is that, once you run out of space in your array, you will have to create a new, bigger one, and copy all the elements to it.

Comment: If you used a linked list, which i am assuming would be a list of nodes that contain right and left pointers, wouldn't insertion also be logarithm? I mean you would compare the data you're trying to insert with the node's data, then go left if smaller, right if bigger. That way you're also eliminating half the tree each time.

Comment: Indeed, if you include pointers to the left and right children then your running time would be better, but then it wouldn't be a linked list :) you would be back to the "normal" implementation of a tree.

Comment: How would you implement it with a linked list then? With one pointer as instance variable? Would it be like the same thing but if left said like 2, you would actually have to physically traverse two nodes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70420/discussion-between-jadhachem-and-committedandroider).

Answer (score 1):

When analyzing algorithms as such, you want to look at what type of binary tree is it (balanced vs. unbalanced), plus the three factors regarding sapce/time complexity:

1. Insertion
2. Deletion
3. Search

Comparing linked list vs. array implementations of binary trees, we see the following:

1. Linked lists insertions and deletions are much less expensive than when done in arrays (think of array element shifts you have to do to fulfill those two operations.
2. Linked lists offer flexible size, while arrays do not; you will have to handle array expansion when data does not fit within initial array size.
3. Arrays offer random access, while linked lists do not; e.g. when dealing with an array implementation of a full or complete binary tree, we can easily compute the indices of any node in the tree.

Having that said, for specific implementations of [Binary Search Trees](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/), linked lists are better implementations simply because in a binary search tree, access follows the rules of a binary search tree (root's value is greater than left child and less than right child).  Therefore, for insertion/deletion and search, average complexity should be `O(log n)`, provided the tree is [balanced](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall09/lecture_notes/lecture04.pdf).  If the binary search tree is not balanced, your complexity becomes `O(n)` for all operations - this is the worst case scenario.

Comment: For a binary search tree, with an array implementation that jadhachem proposed, wouldn't search also have average complexity of O(log n)? If you go through his example, it will take you to left node or right node, meaning half the tree is eliminated each time

Comment: Yes, absolutely, search will yield `O(log n)` on average.  But I am considering also insertions and deletions - in array implementations, those are expensive since you will have to either expand or shift data around.